# Heroku - DelayedJob & Autoscale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scaling, delayed-job

I'm pretty much in wonder of the idea of autoscaling workers on Heroku with this [delayed job branch](http://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling). Only problem is I can't figure out why it won't work.

What I've got thus far:

I've installed the branch as a plugin. 
Added the two lines of configuration as described in the [branch comments](http://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/commit/09d7657e1fc7d25072e6c5e73ede20d6e1185eac#comments):

```
Delayed::Job.destroy_failed_jobs = false
silence_warnings do
  Delayed::Job.const_set("MAX_ATTEMPTS", 3)
  Delayed::Job.const_set("MAX_RUN_TIME", 5.minutes)
  Delayed::Job.auto_scale = true             # < --- this
  Delayed::Job.auto_scale_manager = :heroku  # < --- and this  
end
```

I also added a gem rush as was detailed by another branch commenter.

I am returned the error message:

```
MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- heroku):
```

...which I assume is when my application is trying to communicate with heroku's api. How though to resolve this I'm not clear on. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `heroku` gem to your Gem manifest file (`.gems`) or your Gemfile.

Comment: Ok now why didn't I think of that? Thanks! :)